# Angular Router Resolve not working when task kill and reopen Android Google Chrome

Tags: android, angular

I use Angular Resolve Function to get dynamic data before drawing components.
However, when I open Android Chrome again after having task-killed Android Chrome, the page reload process will be performed but data can not be acquired.

Angular 7.2.7

My Resolver

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalenderByDateResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    const date = route.data.date;
    return this.api.getCalenderByDate(date);
  }
}
```

My Routing Definition

```
{
    path: 'operation/real-time',
    component: RealTimeComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Test Title',
      date: moment()
        .subtract(Number(moment().format('H')) < 4 ? 1 : 0, 'days')
        .format('YYYYMMDD')
    },
    resolve: {
      calender: CalenderByDateResolverService,
      stations: StationsResolverService
      // trips: TripsGroupByOperationsResolverService
    }
},
```

Comment: The value of `route.data.date` will only be set *once* when the application is started. It will not be updated when the route changes, because the router does not reconfigure again. I don't know if this is related to your issue, but base on what I read in the question it doesn't look like what you want.

Comment: I tried to execute moment() in Resolver, but it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I understand.
It's a Service Worker Probrem.

All GET messages are sent to the same Backend URL through the intercepter.

Service Worker caches the result of GET communication to Backend URL.

Therefore, for communication to API URL A, Service Worker returned cache obtained from API URL B.

It solved by giving API URL to the query of Backend URL.